# How do I get jQuery to Load before Bootstrap?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I am building a Bootstrap / WordPress [site](http://turtles.opteradev.com) and I am having an issue with bootstrap.min.js loading before jquery, which results in issues like the navigation not working correctly.

Here is how I have the scripts enqueued.

```
function turtles_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'turtles-bootstrap-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'turtles-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'turtles-bootstap-min-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), 'null', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'turtles-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20120206', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'turtles-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20130115', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'turtles_scripts' );
```

However, when I look at the page source. The Bootstrap is loading before jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://turtles.opteradev.com/wp-content/themes/turtles/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=null'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://turtles.opteradev.com/wp-content/themes/turtles/js/navigation.js?ver=20120206'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://turtles.opteradev.com/wp-content/themes/turtles/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js?ver=20130115'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://turtles.opteradev.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://turtles.opteradev.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://turtles.opteradev.com/wp-content/plugins/ml-slider/assets/sliders/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js?ver=3.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://turtles.opteradev.com/wp-content/plugins/ml-slider-pro/assets/public.js?ver=2.5.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://turtles.opteradev.com/wp-content/plugins/eventON/assets/js/jquery.mobile.min.js?ver=1'></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In place of your emnpty `array()` you are able to declare dependencies.  For Script A to load before Script B, declare that A is dependent on B.

Codex reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

It's possible you have declared these dependencies within your register statements but these are not given above.

Comment: Since jQuery is a default js library already registered by wordpress with name jquery, you can replace your code with this `wp_enqueue_script( 'turtles-bootstap-min-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), 'null', true );`

Answer (score 1):

Just add `array('jquery')`to `wp_enqueue_script` to load the js files after jquery load.